# Dimension line adjustor for plate objects

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

I currently have this idea about a dimension line adjustment tool but having a difficulty creating it. User will call this function and prompt the user of "Select D1" then the selected dimension line would be adjusted to 300mm (1:10 scale) then another prompt of "Select D2 " and then the selected dimension line would be adjusted to 200mm. Any time that the user enters any letter or just a blank, it will end the program and the basis for the distance would always be the dimension line connected to object (yellow rectangle) and not the dimension line connected to the holes inside the object (if there are any).

[image: Ref]